# Image not showing up when values on and off are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I'm creating two sets of radio buttons both with values on and off.

I'm having issues with the code when the buttons are at ON accessories and ON Panels and then the user turns accessories off; the image does not change.

Here is the JS:

```
  var oneOn = $('input:radio[name=one]:checked').val();
  var twoOn = $('input:radio[name=two]:checked').val(); 
  var oneOff = $('input:radio[name=one]:checked').val();
  var twoOff = $('input:radio[name=two]:checked').val();

  $('.radioButton').click(function(e){
   fixButtons(this, selected);
   var selected = $(this).val();
   var oneOn = $('input:radio[name=one]:checked').val();
   var twoOn = $('input:radio[name=two]:checked').val();
   var oneOff = $('input:radio[name=one]:checked').val();
   var twoOff = $('input:radio[name=two]:checked').val();
 if(oneOn === 'on' && twoOn === 'on1') {
  $('.aon_pon').fadeIn('slow');
   }
else if(oneOff === 'off' && twoOff === 'off1'){
  $('.main-img').fadeOut('slow');
}

else if(selected === 'on') {
  $('.aon_poff').fadeIn('slow');
 }
else if(selected === 'off') {
  $('.aon_poff').fadeOut('slow');
}
else if(selected === 'on1') {
  $('.aoff_pon').fadeIn('slow');
}

else if(selected === 'off1'){
  $('.aoff_pon').fadeOut('slow');
}    
 });

 $(":radio[name='one']").attr('checked', true);
 $(":radio[name='two']").attr('checked', true);
```

Heres the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/d0okie0612/m43EQ/

I think my issue is with the z-index maybe, but I've tried adding `.css('z-index', '1000')` and also to the CSS but that does not solve the issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop) to toggle the actual selection state of a radio button:

```
$(":radio[name=one][value=on]").prop('checked', true);
```

Similarly, to check the actual on/off state of a radio button:

```
var oneOn = $('input:radio[name=one][value=on]').prop('checked'); // true or false
```

Comment: so should i use that for my if else statements?

Comment: They would change to something like: `if (oneOn && twoOn) {`

Comment: it still has the same problem where the image isnt changing

Comment: heres a link to the fiddle with your suggestion http://jsfiddle.net/m43EQ/2/ its still having the same problem where the image is not changing when the buttons are ON ON and the OFF ON

Comment: You seem to be fading in one image but not fading out the others: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/m43EQ/3/